# Getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, error-handling, development-environment

I am getting Typescript error while executing
The error is shown below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
at ScapprovalPaymentEventComponent.<anonymous> (http://localhost:50000/main.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:6102:33)
at step (http://localhost:50000/main.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:5940:23)
at Object.next (http://localhost:50000/main.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:5921:53)
at http://localhost:50000/main.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:5915:71
at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:50000/polyfills.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:8553:29)
at push../ClientApp/app/components/forms/scapproval-payment-event/scapproval-payment-event.component.ts.__awaiter (http://localhost:50000/main.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:5911:12)
at push../ClientApp/app/components/forms/scapproval-payment-event/scapproval-payment-event.component.ts.ScapprovalPaymentEventComponent.initializeControls (http://localhost:50000/main.js?v=23.1.0+Build-17.02-1904:6058:16)
```

This is the code:

```
this.totalCount = response.total_rows;
this.bookmark = response.bookmark;
if (isPaginationCall && this.approvedForms && this.approvedForms.length > 0) {
    paymentForms.forEach(x => this.approvedForms.push(x));
} else {
    this.approvedForms = paymentForms;
}
this.onShowRecordChange();
setTimeout(() => {
    this.spinner.hide("MONITORPAYMENT");
}, 0);
```

Comment: You should post the piece of code where you are getting error. Most probably you have not checked for undefined before running loop

Comment: It's not really possible to debug code that we can't see. Please edit your question and add the code where this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.forEach` method with the array. This error shows when you are trying to use the `.forEach` method with other data structure than the array.

Comment: this.totalCount = response.total_rows;
                        this.bookmark = response.bookmark;
                        if (isPaginationCall && this.approvedForms && this.approvedForms.length > 0) {
                            paymentForms.forEach(x => this.approvedForms.push(x));                       
                        }
                        else {
                            this.approvedForms = paymentForms;
                        }
                        this.onShowRecordChange();
                        setTimeout(() => { this.spinner.hide("MONITORPAYMENT"); }, 0);

Comment: This is the part, where I am getting error

Comment: Also, add `paymentForms.length` within the `if` condition like `if (isPaginationCall && this.approvedForms && this.approvedForms.length > 0 && paymentForms.length) `

Comment: you can `console.log(paymentForms)` before the if condition to see if its array or not.